# Solve partial differential equation using method of characteristics.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

**Given:**

$zp + yq = x$

$x_{0} = s$ (x at time t = 0)

$y_{0} = 1$ (y at time t = 0)

$z_{0} = 2s$ (z at time t = 0)

**Approach :**

$ f=zp+yq-x$

Using Characteristic Equations :

$x'(t) = f_{p}$

$y'(t) = f_{q}$

$z'(t) = pf_{p} + qf_{q}$

$p'(t) = -f_{x}-pf_{z}$

$q'(t) = -f_{y}-qf_{z}$

**I got :**

$y=e^{t}$

$p = (1+3e^{2t})/(3e^{2t}-1) $

**But I am not able to proceed further.**

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are partial derivatives of what function with regard to what variable ?

Comment: $p=dz/dx$; $q=dz/dy$

Answer (score 1):

From the comment, the function to be found isn't on the form $f(x,y,z)$ , but $z(x,y)$.

So, the PDE is :
$$z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x \tag 1$$
Characteristic system : $\quad\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{x}\tag 2$

One could parametrize in letting Eq.$(2)$ $=ds$ or $=dt$ depending the common symbolism used. But this case is so simple that it is even not necessary to parametrize.

A first characteristic equation comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dz}{x} \quad\to\quad z^2-x^2=c_1$

A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{c_1+x^2}} \quad\to\quad \frac{\sqrt{c_1+x^2}+x}{y}=c_2=\frac{z+x}{y}$

The general solution of the PDE $(1)$ is expressed on the form of implicit equation :
$$z^2-x^2=F\left(\frac{z+x}{y}\right) \tag 3$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Initial condition : $z(x_0,1)=2x_0\quad\to\quad (2x_0)^2-x_0^2=F\left(\frac{2x_0+x_0}{1}\right)=3x_0^2=F(3x_0)$

The function $F$ is determined : $\quad F(X)=\frac{1}{3}X^2$

Putting this function into Eq.$(3)$, with $X=\frac{z+x}{y}$ leads to : 
$$z^2-x^2=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{z+x}{y}\right)^2$$
Solving for $z$ :
$$z(x,y)=x\frac{3\:y^2+1}{3\:y^2-1}$$

Comment: Hey! Though the solution seems correct but isn't this Lagrangian way of solving PDE rather than Method of characteristics. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is the method of characteristics :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: According to the source you mentioned it seems correct. But my book (MD Raisinghania)  mentions only Cauchy's method of characteristics. The way you explained is mentioned as Lagrange equations.

Comment: As far as I could understand Wikipedia mentions it as characteristic equations. But this is not Method of Characteristics. Correct me if I am wrong.